# Can I detect changes in a node's markup text using dojo?

Tags: dojo

I have a bunch of nodes that will contain markup in an unpredictable structure. I want to be able to watch these nodes and see if the html of the any of the child nodes or their descendants change, no matter how slightly. If they do, then I want to fire an event.

Can I do this through dojo? I'm using 1.10, the latest one.

Thanks.

Comment: you can use dojox/mvc  this will allow you to bind dom to json.  The model usually changes on focus loss of element.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for dom mutations. As far as I'm aware dojo does not provide an api for this, but they're pretty simple to set up. The problem is different browsers have different ways of doing this.

```
var observeNode = document.getElementById('observeMe');

// Check for vendor-specific versions of MutationObserver.
MutationObserver = (function() {
  var prefixes = ['WebKit', 'Moz', 'O', 'Ms', ''];
  for (var i=0, il=prefixes.length; i<il; i++) {
    if (prefixes[i] + 'MutationObserver' in window) {
      return window[prefixes[i] + 'MutationObserver'];
    }
  }
}());

// Sniff for MutationObserver support
if (MutationObserver) {
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    alert('Something changed!');
  });
  observer.observe(observeNode, {attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true});
} else {
  // Fall back to mutation events
  if (observeNode.addEventListener) {
    observeNode.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
      alert('Something changed!');
    });
  }
  // IE8 and below has its own little weird thing
  else {
    observeNode.onpropertychange = function() {
      alert('Something Changed!');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this would probably be sufficient. I wish dojo did this so I could sleep soundly at night knowing someone else is worrying about how its going to work on every browser. But, if it does end up failing it won't be a huge problem